# Secure container for apps- Android

Tags: android, security

I want to make an app like McAfee Secure Container. The container app should launch other (specific) apps and provide them isolated execution environment. There should be no data sharing outside the container and all the apps inside container should use container's network connection.

What can be a way forward?

Comment: Have you found anything on this?

Comment: Only way can be modifying dex code.- @Slartibartfast

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Could you Pls answer your own question with any relevant links or libraries or could you just point me in the right direction.  What part of the dex code would you be modifying and ho would that help build a container etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know one solution that runs each app within it's own dalvik VM with a unique ID (uid ref linux) to protect all resources for that app. It makes use of the linux file permissions to protect these resources. The only way to get apps running with the same UID is to sign it with the same publisher key and declare this ID in the manifest. To get resources world readable you have to declare this explicitly when opening the resources within the app. Further more the apps can only access certain system resources if they declare that permission in the manifest. Think of IO operations and so on. These permissions will than be prompted to the user and install time.

... It's called Android :-)

Or in other words what more do you search for than what is already provided by the Android system? If you're looking for security I would say the Android system is pretty secure on its own. **Some threats I can think of are listed next.**

A possible threat is that the system itself (not the app) is compromised (rooted or so). Then all your app data will be exposed on that system. The solution for that is encrypting your data. [Google for Android Derived Key](http://www.google.be/search?q=android%20derived%20key) for more information on how to get a key from a user password and use that key to encrypt sensitive data stored on a device. The main rule here is to only store sensitive data if you really have to and encrypt it if you do. Also make sure to use CBC mode instead of ECB mode and provide a salt and an IV.

Never ever think that your code is save. Not even if it is obfuscated. Obfuscation does not make it impossible to get the code in a readable format. It just makes it harder. So it's always a bad idea to keep sensitive data in your code.

Another possible threat I can think of is network traffic. Use SSL/TLS and verify hostnames. Limit credentials going over the network by using generated tokens for authentication. Encrypt data over the network, this time use a dynamic IV. Also validate input and be aware of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : you can achieve this with Dynamic Library loading.

Long answer please refer to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siVS2jmPABM